# Why NSURLSessionTask.error and didCompleteWithError delegate?

Tags: swift, swift2, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I start many downloads in a loop and put all my started downloads in an array to track them

When one did successfully complete i remove the downloadTask from the Array:

```
internal func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
```

Then the DownloadTask could also Fail so I also remove it from the Array:

```
internal func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
```

But sometimes some downloads are left in the array, then i found out the ones that are left has an Error Attribute with `unknown error`. But why did it then not fire in the `didCompleteWithError`, like this I have to check for error on two places?

It's not really an issue for me, I'm just wondering?

- [Error Attribute](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiontask/1408145-error?language=objc)
- [DidCompleteWithError](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411610-urlsession)

To extend my question a bit, I also saw you can use `completionHandler` or these `delegates` which should I use? are the some pro/cons. Personally I like the completionHandler more because I would have all code in one place, which would save me a some lines.

Comment: Re completion handler pattern: Yes that's generally easier, but if you're using background session, you have to use delegate-protocol pattern...